# Increase in vandalism of posts

Tags: discussion, editing

Over the past month I have rejected what feels like a lot of edits that are vandalism. I have done some digging into my review history and a large chunk (if not all) of the reviews that I reject because of vandalism appear to be from the same question. This includes four from the last two days.

Has anyone else noticed this and is there anything that can be done?

The question that appears to be edited is: [Using Magento Header and Footer with vBulletin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4648/using-magento-header-and-footer-with-vbulletin/4660#4660)

Comment: Yep...I've been rejecting the same thing over and over again. Is there a way to restrict anonymous editing?

Comment: I do not see any editing notice on the question. Was there already action taken by Tim or benmarks?

Comment: I've seen the same edit plaguing that same question and have rejected it multiple times myself as well. Wondering if it's a bot targeting that one question, or if it's a bot targeting things related to vBulletin. :)

Comment: Hi, I'm the one who answered that question. I was wondering if I gave an insufficient answer and someone is being a jerk and spamming that post? Do you guys think I should just remove my answer, since it really didn't offer a clear answer to the question?

Comment: @ryanF. I think you should leave your answer as it is. I see that is has one upvote, so at least one person liked it. Maybe it will serve someone else. It's not like the website has hundreds of edits daily and it's hard to manage. I think we can manage to reject the vandalism from time to time if there is no other solution.

Comment: @Marius, thanks for the feedback. I'll go ahead and follow your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Same here - hundreds of them. I pointed this out on Twitter some time ago. https://twitter.com/philwinkle/status/418846950083936256

Comment: We've just rolled out a behind-the-scenes new feature that _should_ greatly reduce the number of garbage edits at that question (and across the network). If you're still seeing this sort of thing in a few days, let me know!

Comment: @Pops thanks for letting us know

Comment: Just yesterday I flagged a post which hijacked @FabianBlechschmidt account.

Comment: @Pops it appears that this particular post is happening more than before now :(

Comment: @DavidManners I'll have a look.

Comment: @DavidManners so, apparently, I lied before... somehow, the new garbage edit blocker didn't get applied to Magento. It should be enabled now for real. Don't hesitate to ping again if it keeps happening!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We rolled out a honeypot system for this, however, it was still on the default threshold and configuration settings for Magento. I tweaked these numbers quite a bit based on your actual volume, and it should begin to quiet down noticeably in a short amount of time.

I'm sorry about that, I thought for certain that I had visited and adjusted all of the sites that tend to get a large volume of spam edits, but somehow Magento escaped me. It's set now, and I can crank it up a bit more if needed going forward.

Anyway, it should kick in soon. My email address is in my profile, the Magento moderators can reach out to me directly if things appear to need further adjustment.

Comment: This has picked up again, I'm getting a steady stream all day most days.